# Is it possible to receive notification on Twitter Mention?

Tags: api, http, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've written an app that will hopefully have its data updated when a Twitter user mentions my Twitter user name in a tweet. Simply put I've written a Score Board app and I'd like Twitter users to be able to tweet their best times which my app would then respond to:

@HankHendrix 45:12

I'm new to the Twitter API and already I've experienced difficulty finding the answers to my questions. I can't even find an IRC channel!

I am aware you can GET the mentions of a user via OAuth - I could CRON a script every 30 seconds to do this and then update my DB but ideally I'd like to be able to trigger a script in real-time (like long-polling).

This might be possible through the Twitter Streaming API - but again, the documentation doesn't appear to be noob friendly.

What are the solutions? I'm open to Node and Web Sockets etc.

Comment: not be friendly and not be fresh enough. about your post: [mentions_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline).

#twitterapi on freenode

Comment: What does that first sentence mean?